# Nested definition: How can I define a function with a passed-in expression?

Tags: function-construction, scoping, assignment, faq

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
SetAttributes[def, HoldFirst]
def[s_Symbol, v_] := (s[x_] := v)
def[f, x^2]
f[3] (* Expected result: 9 *)
(*
  x^2
*)
?f (* Expected result: f[x_] := x^2 *)
(*
  Global`f

  f[x$_] := x^2
*)
```

Obviously the `x` in the `x_` pattern gets replaced by `x$`. Is there a way I can prevent that? That is, from calling `def[f,x^2]` I want to result the definition `f[x_] := x^2`. I don't of course care about the name of the variable, so if the resulting function definition reads `f[x$_] := x$^2` I'm fine with that, too.

I tried

```
def[s_Symbol, v_] := With[{x$ = x}, s[x_] := v]
def[s_Symbol, v_] := With[{x = x$}, s[x_] := v]
def[s_Symbol, v_] := (s[x_] := v) /. x :> x$
```

and

```
def[s_Symbol, v_] := (s[x_] := v) /. x$ :> x
```

but none worked.

Comment: How about `SetAttributes[def, HoldFirst]; def[s_Symbol, v_] := With[{temp = v}, s = Function @@ {x, temp}]`?

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks, I didn't think of anonymous functions; that's a solution that indeed works for my case.

Comment: @J.M.: I have to retract that it works for my problem: I just noticed that anonymous functions don't seem to support optional arguments.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With your proposed definition style, the user of that function def has to know that v could/should/must depend on x for this to work; x really should be an argument of def. Perhaps something like this were better suited.

```
ClearAll[def]
ClearAll[f]
(*SetAttributes[def,HoldFirst]*)

def[s_Symbol, v_, vars_List] := 
 With[{h = s @@ (Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ vars)}, (h := v)]
def[f, x^2, {x}]

f[3]
(* 9 *)
```

Comment: This indirect pattern building did the trick!

Answer (score 20):

Try for example

```
SetAttributes[def, HoldAll]
def[s_Symbol, v_] := Function[Null, s[x_] := #, HoldFirst][v]
```

Unnamed functions just don't care :)

Other alternatives that should also work (but I would use the previous approach)

```
def[s_Symbol, v_] := Identity[SetDelayed][HoldPattern@s[x_], v];
def[s_Symbol, v_] := Unevaluated[s[x_] := "Hello"] /. "Hello" -> v
```

Comment: Elegant! +1. (I edited to better respect the semantics of `SetDelayed`. If you don't like the result, feel free to revert!)

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrR. Your edit is fine. I had done it that way based on the question being `HoldFirst`, but `HoldAll` makes more sense to me too

Answer (score 11):

I propose these:

```
SetAttributes[def, HoldAllComplete]

def[s_Symbol, v_] := SetDelayed @@ Hold[s[x_], v]

def[s_Symbol, v_] := With[{L := s[x_]}, L := v]

def[s_Symbol, v_] := Reverse @ Unevaluated[v := s[x_]]
```

The [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAllComplete.html) (or [`SequenceHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SequenceHold.html)) attribute is necessary for an assignment such as:

```
def[q, Sequence[1, 2, x]]

head[q[5]]
```

> ```
> head[1, 2, 5]
> ```

Also see:

- [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766)