# replacement rules from a pattern and a matching expression

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

(This seems to be a very basic necessity in a language having pattern-matching capabilities such as Mathematica, yet I struggled for many hours to find a common solution to this problem.)

Suppose there is a pattern with some of its sub-elements named, and there is an expression that matches it. How do I generate a list of replacement rules that maps sub-element names into their values in the matching expression? E.g.,

```
patt=f_[_, s_, x___];
expr=ab[c, d, e, f];
mkMatchRules[expr,patt]
>> {f -> ab, s -> d, x -> Sequence[e, f]}
```

I have written a solution to this,

```
collectAllPattVars[patt_] := Union[Map[Part[#, 1] &,
  Cases[patt, _Pattern, {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True]]];
mkMatchRules[expr_, patt_] := Module[
  {pattVars = collectAllPattVars[patt], mkRhs},
  mkRhs = Block[{$}, ReleaseHold[Hold[patt :> $] /. $ -> With[{$ = Map[List, pattVars]}, $]]]; 
  If[MatchQ[expr, patt],
     MapThread[Rule[#1, If[Length[#2] == 1, #2[[1]], Sequence @@ #2]] &, 
               {pattVars, Replace[expr, mkRhs]}],
     $Failed]];
```

which produces the result in the example above
However, I hope somebody knows a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Interesting question. +1 :-)

Comment: Also, welcome to Mathematica.SE, and thank you for properly formatting your question.

Answer (score 22):

I like this question.  If you can be assured that none of the pattern names will have values assigned I believe this can be done rather simply.  If however any of (`f`, `s`, `x`) in the example have assignments additional guards will be required.

### The simple case

```
patt = f_[_, s_, x___];
expr = ab[c, d, e, f];

f1 = # -> (expr /. patt -> #) &;

Cases[patt, Verbatim[Pattern][name_, _] :> f1[name], -1, Heads -> True]
```

> ```
> {f -> ab, s -> d, x -> Sequence[e, f]}
> ```

Or more concisely, if further assuming that the subexpressions will be evaluated:

```
Reap[patt /. Pattern -> (Sow @ f1 @ # &)][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {f -> ab, s -> d, x -> Sequence[e, f]}
> ```

### More robustly

Now as a complete function and with proper holding of pattern names:

```
x = "Failed!"; (* This should not appear in the result! *)

mkMatchRules[expr_, patt_] /; MatchQ[expr, patt] :=
  Module[{p = patt},
    Cases[patt,
      Verbatim[Pattern][name_, _] :>
        (HoldForm[name] -> (expr /. p :> name)),
      -1, Heads -> True
    ]
  ]

mkMatchRules[ ab[c, d, e, f], f_[_, s_, x___] ]
```

> ```
> {f -> ab, s -> d, x -> Sequence[e, f]}
> ```

Note that in the output the LHS sybols are wrapped in `HoldForm`.  Other options are `Defer` or converting to strings.

---

I originally used a rather convoluted method featuring `Function` to avoid a certain problem wherein pattern names are automatically changed within scoping constructs.  This is done to avoid collisions but it prevents exactly the behavior I need.  I revised the code to use another method that is hopefully more transparent and also cleaner.  It works by preventing the direct substitution (by `SetDelayed`) of the pattern into the inner replacement using a localized proxy symbol `p`.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! 
Is there a reason you use
    Function[Null,<body>,...]
construction? to force the parameter variable to be temporary?

Comment: @Sergey Yes, there is.  I needed it to avoid automatic renaming within nested scoping constructs that breaks this otherwise.  I shall see if I can find a prior question that addresses this.

Comment: @Sergey I couldn't find the particular question I was looking for (I may need to ask Leonid or Rojo) but here is an example: `Function[name, ab[c, d, e, f] /. f_[_, s_, x___] :> name, HoldAll][x] // Trace` -- look at the output of the `Trace` and you will see `ab[c, d, e, f] /. f$_[_, s$_, x$___] :> x` where `x` has become `x$` etc.  This is *Mathematica* trying to respect/protect the nested scoping constructs (both `Function` and `RuleDelayed` are scoping constructs, along with the more known `With`, `Block`, `Module`).  Sometimes however this is exactly what you *don't want*. (continued)

Comment: `Function` as used with `Slot` rather than named parameters does not cause this automatic renaming.  In this case I needed a Hold attribute as well and I had to use an undocumented form: `Function[Null, (* body with #, #2 *), attribute]` which I learned from Leonid Shifrin.

Comment: @Sergey I updated my answer to eliminate this rather baroque and undocumented construct.  I believe it is now both cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: @Sergey I found [a post that deals with this renaming](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13757/121), though it is not the one I was thinking of.

Comment: @Sergey [here is another one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10086/121)

Comment: Er……how can I make `"Failed!"` appear in the result?

Comment: @xzczd The point is to *not* have `"Failed!"` appear in the result.  You will see the failure if you use the "simple case" code after defining `x = "Failed!"`; it returns: `{f -> ab, s -> d, "Failed!" -> "Failed!"}`