# How to visualize pattern matching process?

Tags: pattern-matching, visualization, core-language, code-review

I want a function that does the same job like `ReplaceRepeated`, and can make the matching process visible.

I searched the Internet but didn't find any existing code or package that meets my requirement, so I tried to write one:

```
Clear[myReplaceRepeated];
myReplaceRepeated[lis_List, rule_, n_: Infinity] := 
Module[{variables, mat = rule[[1]], data, tem}, 
variables = 
ToExpression@
StringCases[
 ToString[mat], (vars : WordCharacter ..) ~~ "_" | "__" | "___" :> vars];
If[variables != {},

testQ = Table[Cases[#1, #2 -> i, {0}], {i, variables}] &;
data = 
Reap[FixedPointList[(Sow[testQ[#, mat]]; # /. rule) &, lis, 
   n]][[2, 1]]; 
Labeled[Grid[Prepend[data, variables], Frame -> All, 
 Background -> {Lighter /@ 
    Hue /@ Range[0, 1, 1/Length[variables]]}], 
Column[{lis, "the rule is", rule}], Top],

Labeled[
Grid[tem = Most@FixedPointList[# /. rule &, lis, n], Frame -> All,
  Background -> {None, {Lighter /@ 
     Hue /@ Range[0, 1, 1/Length[tem]]}}], 
Column[{lis, "the rule is", rule}], Top]
]]
```

It works in some cases:

***Example 1***

```
myReplaceRepeated[{1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 1, 8}, 
{Longest[a___], b_, c__, b_, d___} -> {b, b, a, c, d}]
```

[image]

***Example 2***

```
myReplaceRepeated[{1, a, 2, b, 3, c}, _?NumericQ -> F[Infinity], 4](*4 is set the MaxIterations*)
```

[image: From "Mathematica Cookbook"]

***Example 3***

```
myReplaceRepeated[{1, 2}, {a_, b_} -> {{a}, {b}}, 5]](*5 is also set the MaxIterations*)
```

[image: From "Mathematica Cookbook"]

but fails in some other cases:

```
myReplaceRepeated[f[a][b][c][d], g_[x_][y__] -> g[x, y]]
myReplaceRepeated[Log[Sqrt[a (b c^d)^e]], {Log[x_ y_] :> Log[x] + Log[y], Log[x_^k_] :> k Log[x]}]
```

How to improve my `myReplaceRepeated`?

Is there really no existing tool for the visualization of pattern matching?

***Edit:***

Let me explain my function with the following example.

```
lis = {1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 1, 8};
rule = {Longest[a___], b_, c__, b_, d___} -> {b, b, a, c, d};
mat(*short for match*) = rule[[1]];
```

I want to know how those *variables* i.e. `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` in `rule` match the sub-sequence in `lis` when `lis //. rule` executes.

To monitor how those *variables* match, I need to first know what *variables* `rule` contain:

```
variables = 
ToExpression@StringCases[
ToString[mat], (vars : WordCharacter ..) ~~ "_" | "__" | "___" :> vars]
```

> {a, b, c, b, d}

Then I find out how these *variables* match `lis` respectively, for example the following piece of code shows `a` matches `1, 3, 1, 4` in `lis`.

**Notice the level is `{0}`, otherwise we get `{}`**

```
Cases[{1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 1, 
8}, {Longest[a___], b_, c__, b_, d___} -> a, {0}]
```

> {1, 3, 1, 4}

These are combined in a loop.

```
Table[Cases[{1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 1, 
8}, {Longest[a___], b_, c__, b_, d___} -> i, {0}], {i, variables}]
```

> {{1, 3, 1, 4}, {1}, {3, 4, 2, 7}, {1}, {8}}

The output means `a` represents `{1, 3, 1, 4}`,`b` represents `{1}`, `c` represents `{3, 4, 2, 7}`, the next `b` represents the latter `{1}` and `d` represents `{8}` in `lis`.

Then I define a `testQ`  to combine all these together:

```
testQ = Module[{variables}, 
variables = 
 ToExpression@
  StringCases[
   ToString[#2], (vars : WordCharacter ..) ~~ 
     "_" | "__" | "___" :> vars];
Table[Cases[#1, #2 -> i, {0}], {i, variables}]] &;
testQ[lis, mat]
```

> {{1, 3, 1, 4}, {1}, {3, 4, 2, 7}, {1}, {8}}

The functionality of `ReplaceRepeated` is achieved by `FixedPointList`:

```
 data = Reap[
 FixedPointList[(Sow[
   testQ[#, 
    mat]]; # /. {Longest[a___], b_, c__, b_, d___} -> {b, b, a, c,
      d}) &, {1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 1, 8}]][[2, 1]];
 Grid@data
```

> [image]

This is almost the output of *example 1*, except for the coloring.

You may noticed that the `variables` in the above code can't be `{}`, so a `rule` like

```
  lis = {1, a, 2, b, 3, c}; rule = _?NumericQ -> F[Infinity]; 
  variables = 
  ToExpression@
  StringCases[
  ToString[mat], (vars : WordCharacter ..) ~~ "_" | "__" | "___" :> vars]
```

> {}

will cause problem, that's why I add a `If` in `myReplaceRepeated`.

So long my code gets the ability to handle *example 1 ~ 3*, but if `lis` and `rule` are:

```
lis = f[a][b][c][d]; rule = g_[x_][y__] -> g[x, y]; mat = rule[[1]]; 
variables = 
ToExpression@
StringCases[
ToString[mat], (vars : WordCharacter ..) ~~ "_" | "__" | "___" :> 
vars]!={}
```

> True

My program fails, how to fix it?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I don't quite understand the rule of the colorization. Could you explain it more please?

Comment: I tried to improve the expressions of your question. (Wish I didn't make it worse… ) Well, To be honest, personally I feel your **Edit** a little verbose…

Comment: @xzczd Thank you indeed. Your English is better than mine. SE is really have a typeset than Baidu tieba sites.

Comment: Related: [(17660)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17660/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There exists a simple trick for your purpose, here is my implementation:

```
f[a][b][c][d] //. g_[x_][y__] :> g[x, y] /; (Print[g[x][y] -> g[x, y]]; True)
```

[image]

```
Log[Sqrt[a (b c^d)^e]] //.
 {Log[x_ y_] :> Log[x] + Log[y] /; (Print[Log[x y] -> Log[x] + Log[y]]; True),
  Log[x_^k_] :> k Log[x] /; (Print[Log[x^k] -> k Log[x]]; True)}
```

[image]

Not as colorful as yours, but you can use the trick therein as the core of your `myReplaceRepeated`.

---

**Update**

Here's my trial for a general function monitoring pattern-matching. Needless to say, achieving a perfectly general monitoring function is hard and I'm sure (Yeah, sure) my function will fail under more complicated situations, but it at least works for your samples.

```
ClearAll[show]
SetAttributes[show, HoldAll]
show[f_] := 
 Module[{i = 1}, 
  Quiet[ReleaseHold[
    Hold[f] /. 
      (Except[MaxIterations, a_] -> b_) :> a :> Evaluate[b] /. 
      (a_ :> b_) :> 
        a :> b /; (Print[(a /. Longest | Shortest | Repeated | RepeatedNull -> List /. 
                     Pattern :> 
                       Composition[Evaluate, Sequence @@ # &, 
                         With[{color = ColorData[1][i++]}, (Style[#, color] &) /@ #] &, 
                         Most, List]) -> b]; 
                  True)], 
  RuleDelayed::rhs]]
```

This function is (naively) attempted to handle all the code involving pattern-matching that explicitly containing `Rule` or `RuleDelayed`. Let's try it.

***Example 1:***

```
show[{1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 1, 8} //. 
       {Longest[a___], b_, c__, b_, d___} :> {b, b, a, c, d}]
```

[image]

Here the scope of different patterns are marked by different colors, and the scope of `Longest` is additionally marked by `{}`.

***Example 2:***

```
show@ReplaceRepeated[{1, a, 2, b}, _?NumericQ -> F[Infinity], MaxIterations -> 2]
```

[image]

<strike>To relieve the embarrassment I cut down the size of this example,</strike> I admit that for this example the visual effect of your `myReplaceRepeated` beats my `show`, but `show` does monitor the matching process.

***Example 3:***

```
show@ReplaceRepeated[{1, 2}, {a_, b_} -> {{a}, {b}}, MaxIterations -> 5]
```

[image]

Notice in this and the previous example the `Except[MaxIterations, a_]` part in the definition of `show` plays a role. If you want to make this function more general, more exceptions should be included in this part. (Or maybe I should think out a completely new testing method?)

***Example 4:***

```
show[f[a][b][c][d] //. g_[x_][y__] -> g[x, y]]
```

[image]

Notice that in this example the `Evaluate` inside `Composition` is necessary or the `Sequence` won't disappear.

***Example 5:***

```
show[Log[Sqrt[a (b c^d)^e]] //. {Log[x_ y_] :> Log[x] + Log[y], Log[x_^k_] :> k Log[x]}]
```

[image]

This example is actually the simplest among the 5.

As mentioned above, the `show` function is still quite incomplete, but you can use it as a start. I may also improve it later, but now I'd like to go to bed :)

Comment: You may want to look into using `Reap` and `Sow` instead of `Print` if you want full control of the outputted rules.

Comment: @ChipHurst I understand what you mean.If I use Sow and Reap and combine his method,my solution can be shorter

Comment: @ChipHurst Yeah, `Reap` and `Sow` is undoubtedly a better choice. The initial intention of this answer is only to show that trick so I chose the relatively simpler `Print` to avoid distraction :)

Comment: @user15961 You don't need to accept that quick, feel free to wait for 24 hours or more so your question may attract better answers.

Comment: Ok,I know..I cancel the accept button

Comment: Regarding evaluation you *might* find interest in my `mkMatchRules` function posted in answer to the question linked in the comment below this question.  You already have my vote of course.