# Obtaining the number of iterations used in ReplaceRepeated

Tags: replacement, options

`ReplaceRepeated` has an option `MaxIterations` which indicates Mathematica is keeping track of the number of iterations.  Is there a way to obtain the actual number of iterations used in an evaluation of `ReplaceRepeated`?

(The use case is to obtain the [additive persistence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdditivePersistence.html) of a number by counting the number of times we use a rule that sums digits until we end up with a single digit)

```
number = 11113132434242342342342342535646657758768872132131111119
sumrule = value_ :> Total[IntegerDigits[value]]
number //. sumrule
(*  and ideally a magic function, e.g., count = `InternalValue`Iterations  etc  *)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to visualize pattern matching process?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73685/how-to-visualize-pattern-matching-process)

Comment: @xzczd I don't see the duplication.  The linked Q/answer/comments describe an entirely new function to visualize replace steps. Yes, you can count the iterations it uses. But I'm just seeking a single value query/return using the built-in `ReplaceRepeated`.

Comment: But you're asking for "a way to obtain the actual number of replacement operation", not a option of `ReplaceRepeated` that demonstrate the actual number of replacement operation :)

Comment: Edits made for 'clarity'

Comment: Tangentially related: [(20181)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20181/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we wish to handle an arbitrary list of rules in the second parameter of `ReplaceRepeated` we can by using a single wrapping rule with a counter and handing off the actual processing to `ReplaceAll`.  This avoids the memory overhead of keeping all intermediate results for `FixedPointList`.

```
countReplace[expr_, rules_] :=
  Module[{i = -1},
    {expr //. all_ :> (i++; all /. rules), i}
  ]
```

Example:

```
countReplace[
  {17, 4381, 423},
  {x_ /; x > 200 :> x/2, x_ /; x > 10 :> x - 1, x_?Positive :> x - 0.3}
]
```

> ```
> {{-0.2, -0.29375, -0.15}, 166}
> ```

This also works inside held expressions, as mentioned by Jacob:

```
countReplace[Hold[1728], n_Integer :> RuleCondition[n/2]]
```

> ```
> {Hold[27/2], 7}
> ```

The example is contrived as I couldn't think of another replacement that would not be infinite.  [`RuleCondition`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/121) is used to force evaluation of the right-hand-side; that behavior is *not* characteristic of `countReplace` itself.  *Update:* With Jacob's own example:

```
c = 3;

countReplace[HoldComplete @ Hold @ Hold @ c, Hold[c] :> c]
```

> ```
> {HoldComplete[c], 2}
> ```

Comment: +1 for the embedded counter and starting at -1.

Comment: +1. It took me a while to realise why the examples would cause infinite replacement and it was luck that my own example did not suffer from it. I also like the name `countReplace`.

Comment: there's deep and then there's Mr Wizard DEEP !   Learning so much !

Comment: @PlaysDice And then there is [**Leonid**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin?tab=answers&sort=votes) *deep*.  If you haven't discovered *that* layer yet order food in; you'll be reading for a while. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

```
i = 0;
number = 11113132434242342342342342535646657758768872132131111119;
sumrule = value_ :> (i++; Total[IntegerDigits[value]]);
number //. sumrule
i
```

This is a quick and dirty way to do this.

Comment: Hah! I didn't know you could just put a counter in a rule.  I like quick and dirty. It seems to give an answer that is +1, perhaps due to a final 'ReplaceRepeated' which finds that there is no change.  I can easily subtract one

Comment: `ReplaceRepeated` needs to try one more time to do a `ReplaceAll` after `value` reaches `9` in order to verify that it is done.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution, that works with a list of rules and with held expressions

```
cRepRep2[expr_, snd_] :=
 {Last@#, Length@# - 2} &@
  FixedPointList[# /. snd &, expr]
```

Here is a similar solution, that saves on memory by using `FixedPoint` rather than `FixedPointList`. It also works with held expressions

```
cRepRep3[expr_, snd_] :=
 Module[
  {c = -1, resExpr},
  resExpr = 
   FixedPoint[# /. snd &, expr, SameTest -> ((c++; SameQ[#, #2]) &)];
  {resExpr, c}
  ]
```

Below is the dirty way made into a function, which is less nice than the other solutions.

```
cRepRep[expr_, (Rule | RuleDelayed)[pat_, rep_]] :=
 Module[{c = 0},
  {ReplaceRepeated[expr, pat :> (c++; rep)], c}
  ]
```

Here is function that tries to let all the replacements be done by `ReplaceRepeated`, while also working for held expressions. Unfortunately there is a problem with it, which it shares with `cRepRep`, as we will see further below.

```
cRepRep4[expr_, (Rule | RuleDelayed)[pat_, rep_]] :=     
 cRepRep4[expr, {pat :> rep}]

cRepRep4[expr_, rules_List] :=
 Module[{c = 0, rLen, cIncrCondArrHeld, repsHeld, newRepsHeld, 
   newRulesHeld, resExpr},
  rLen = Length[rules];
  cIncrCondArrHeld = 
   DeleteCases[Hold@Evaluate@ConstantArray[Hold[c++; True], rLen], 
    Hold, {2, Infinity}, Heads -> True];
  repsHeld = Hold[rules][[All, All, 2]];
  newRepsHeld = 
   Apply[
    Condition, 
    Hold@Evaluate@Thread[Join[repsHeld, cIncrCondArrHeld]], {2}];
  newRulesHeld =
   Apply[RuleDelayed, 
    Hold@Evaluate@Thread@Prepend[newRepsHeld, rules[[All, 1]]], {2}];
  resExpr =
   ReplacePart[
    {
     expr,
     newRulesHeld
     }
    ,
    {0 -> ReplaceRepeated, {2, 0} -> Unevaluated}

    ];
  {resExpr, c}
  ]
```

Unfortunately `ReplaceRepeated` can terminate in two ways, which causes trouble. Either it makes a last replacement which results in the same expression, or all the rules fail to match. I think it is not straightforward, if at all possible, to get this information from `ReplaceRepeated`. Therefore `cRepRep`, `cRepRep4` will fail, like in the following example.

```
c = 0; (*just to make things harder*)
cRepRep4[HoldComplete@Hold@Hold@c, {Hold[c] :> c}]
cRepRep4[number, {9-> 8, sumrule}]
```

> ```
> {HoldComplete[c], 2} (*correct*)
> {8, 5} (*count is one too high*)
> ```

Mr.Wizard's solution does not suffer from this because the replacement by the rules is really done by `ReplaceAll` and the rule in `ReplaceRepeated` always matches, so that `ReplaceRepeated` always terminates because of "identical expressions".

Good examples

```
c = 3; (*just to make things harder*)
cRepRep3[HoldComplete@Hold@Hold@c, Hold[c] :> c]
cRepRep3[number, {9 -> 8, sumrule}]
```

> ```
> {HoldComplete[c], 2}
> {8, 4}
> ```

Comment: Nice, thank you.  Like Carlo's answer, it gives +1 more iterations than is 'needed', but I'm guessing MMA includes the final iteration where it sees no change from the (pen)ultimate iteration. So the MMA calculation requires #iterations + (1 final step with no change).   but 'real world' iterations are  c minus 1.

Comment: `ReplaceRepeated` is able to handle a list of rules; it appears this function is not.  Can you fix that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ah yes I was not satisfied anyway. Let's see

Comment: Cool.  `cRepRep2` gives the 'correct' answer for iterations = 3.  Nice hinting by @Mr.Wizard with  `FixedPointList` and his [20181](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20180/how-to-remove-redundant-from-a-nested-list-of-lists/20181#20181)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because `FixedPointList`  captures *all steps leading to completion*.  So, although I asked about just counting `ReplaceRepeated` steps, the cRepRep2 approach here provides both that solution and points to the broader utility of `FPL` to capture the repeated operations.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I went into a coding frenzy, but failed to find a solution that uses `ReplaceRepeated`. My mistake was that I thought adding a rule `_/;(c++;False)` to the beginning of the list of rules would work, but here `c++` gets evaluated to often. It is also hard to make things work for held expressions, as the original approach fails here.

Comment: @Jacob I posted an answer with what I was thinking.  (You already have my vote on yours.)

Comment: @Jacob I added an example with held expressions but it is a very poor one; can you think of something better?