Create progress bar for Cases function
Is there a way to create a dynamic progress bar for a Cases function? For instance, when selecting elements from a large list using Cases. Previous solutions work with an iterator (e.g. here) and I don't see a way how to use this with Cases.
Here is an (extremly simplified) example:
list1={{a,b},{c,d},{e,f},{g,h},{i,j},{k,l},{m,n},{o,p}};

list2={d,h,p};

Now I want to select those rows in list1 like this:
list3 = Cases[list1, _?(MemberQ[list2, #[[2]]] &)]

Is there a way to add a progress bar in order to see how much time it takes to do this for a very large list?
Many thanks in advance.

Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73685/1871

@xzczd: thx but I am not sure if this is really related. I dont want to visualize the matching process but the progress of computation..

The progress of computation of Cases is exactly a matching process. The simplest modification for my show therein to make it a monitor is to modify the Print to PrintTemporary. (Notice the matching process is usually very fast, you probably need to add a Pause somewhere to slow down the code a bit. ) Or you actually want to monitor something else? If so, please be more specific.

@xzczd: I just want to see a bar which shows the computation progress. Just want to see how long it takes to finish it. Had to abort the evaluation becaues after 2 days was still not finished. Probably there is a way to modify your showbut my skills are limited to see it...

Still, you need to be more specific. Depending on the arguments of Cases, the degree of difficulty for monitoring will be quite different. For example, if it's e.g. Cases[Range[10], a_/;OddQ[a]], then monitoring is simple, we just need to check the current position of pattern matcher, but if we're matching e.g. Cases[(2 + x (7 + 2 y (-4^(5 y) + 11 z)))/(1 + (-3 + y) x), a_. y, Infinity], then defining a process is already challenging. Also, please notice that, even the monitors in the link you've found won't tell you how long the code will take.

Please add this to the body of question. Also, it's better to provide sample code for defining list1 and list2.

@xzczd see above. thx!

i = 0;
Monitor[
  list3 = Cases[list1, _?(i++; MemberQ[list2, #[[2]]] &)], 
  ProgressIndicator[i, {0, Length@list1}]]; // AbsoluteTiming

However, given that you're using PatternTest (?) in Cases, the Cases can be easily replaced with a Select, then we can use ResourceFunction["MonitorProgress"]:
list3 = ResourceFunction["MonitorProgress"]@
    Select[list1, MemberQ[list2, #[[2]]] &]; // AbsoluteTiming

And, at least for this specific problem, the following solution is faster:
list3 = Cases[list1, {_, Alternatives @@ list2}]; // AbsoluteTiming

It can also be monitored, of course:
i = 0; 
list3 = 
  Monitor[Cases[list1, {_, Alternatives @@ list2} /; (i++; True)], 
   ProgressIndicator[i, {0, Length@list1}]]; // AbsoluteTiming

It's not hard to write a general function adds progress indicator for Cases:
caseprogress = 
  Function[expr, 
   Unevaluated@expr /. 
    HoldPattern@Cases[lst_, patt_, rst___] :> 
     Module[{i = 0}, 
      Monitor[Cases[lst, patt /; (i++; True)], 
       ProgressIndicator[i, {0, Length@lst}]]], HoldAll];

Usage:
list3 = Cases[list1, _?(MemberQ[list2, #[[2]]] &)]; // caseprogress

But notice caseprogress is useful only for monitoring the matching process in the first level of expression e.g. the matching of elements in 1D list. As pointed out in the comment above, for complicated cases like
Cases[(2 + x (7 + 2 y (-4^(5 y) + 11 z)))/(1 + (-3 + y) x), a_. y, Infinity]

there doesn't even exist an obvious way to define the progress.

Thx for providing the much faster solution with Alternatives! However in this case the ProgressIndicatordoes not "move" (i.e. the bar remains empty) but suddenly the computation is finished. Could it be that this is a highly non-linear process (i.e. starts slowly but then accelerates so fast that I cannot see the progress in the bar?)

@M.A. I guess it's because the calculation is too fast for your sample. You may try e.g. SeedRandom["progress"]; range = CharacterRange["a", "z"] // ToExpression; list1 = RandomChoice[range, {10^6, 2}]; list2 = RandomChoice[range, 4000]; for testing.

@M.A. Thx for accepting. (Actually you don't need to accept so fast, it's perfectly OK to wait a day or even longer to attract more answers :) . )

Thx, will keep that in mind for future questions :-) However, after a more detailed observation of the evaluation process, I know can confirm: After 4 hours or so the progress bar is at 4-5% but suddenly the evaluation is finished. Either something is still wrong with the iterator (I am only referring to the solution with Alternativeswhich is, ironically, the real solution to my problem of monitoring an otherwise lenghty computation) or the underlying process  takes place at different speeds... (thx again but I have now unchecked the accepted button)

@M.A. The underlying monitor method of my answer is simple and straightforward (every time an element of the list is checked, i+1) so I don't think there's anything wrong in counting side. Might be something related to front-end refresh, if I have to guess (see e.g. Possible Issues section of document of Monitor). If you can reproduce the behavior with a reasonably small sample, I think it'll be OK to ask a separate question for this.

Ok I now found out that the progress bar works perfectly for my initial solution (with MemberQ) but not for your specific (and much faster) solution (with Alternatives)...

@M.A. Have you tried the Refresh method as mentioned in my last comment? Alternatively, try e.g. i = 0; list3 = Monitor[Cases[list1, {_, Alternatives @@ list2} /; (i++; True)], Column@{DateString[], ProgressIndicator[i, {0, Length@list1}]}]; // AbsoluteTiming If the front-end isn't updating properly, then you should find the clock strange.

Ok I have no asked a separate question which includes a sample. Hope this is okay. Thx
