# Using predefined expressions as free variables in a pure function

Tags: function-construction, scoping, pure-function

I want to have a function value of an expression where some variables are solutions to some set of equations, with some values of parameters. I had an idea to use pure functions for that.

However, since both the expression and the equations are lengthy I'd like to place them in a separate expressions defined earlier on. Here is Minimal Working Example:

```
MWE1 = b x^2 + a y^2 + 3 + δ;
Dx = D[MWE1, x];
Dy = D[MWE1, y];
MWF[a_, b_] := 
  Function[{δ}, (Evaluate[MWE1]) /. 
    FindRoot[
      {Evaluate[Dx] == 0, Evaluate[Dy] == 0}, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]]
```

And here is an attempt to test it:

```
test3 = MWF[1, 1];
test3[1]
```

> ```
>  3 + b x^2 + a y^2 + δ /. 
>      FindRoot[
>       {Evaluate[Dx] == 0, Evaluate[Dy] == 0}, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}},
>       AccuracyGoal -> ∞]
> ```

However, if I paste the expressions `MWE1`, `Dx`, `Dy` directly to the definition of `MWF`, the function works like charm.

Is it possible to use predefined expressions inside the definition? Do so would make the code much clearer.

Comment: Have a look at `With`

Comment: @Sascha Yes but that tends to mess things up due to how scoping is implemented using variable renaming.  `Replace` is better, but can also end up with surprising results, see my answer.  I don't have a good solution! :'(

Comment: @Szabolcs very good point, I haven't though of that at all

Comment: Related: [(10086)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10086/121),
[(11461)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11461/121),
[(13757)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13757/121),
[(20766)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/121),
[(46751)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46751/121),
[(69590)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is quite simple and fundamental: you try to use *lexical scoping* (`SetDelayed` and `Function`) as it would be *dynamic scoping* (`Block`). So your problem can be solved easily by outsourcing the dynamic scoping to `Block` with minimal modification of your original code:

```
MWE1 = b x^2 + a y^2 + 3 + δ;
Dx = D[MWE1, x];
Dy = D[MWE1, y];
MWF[aa_, bb_] = 
 Function[{δδ}, 
  Block[{δ = δδ, a = aa, b = bb}, 
   MWE1 /. FindRoot[{Dx == 0, Dy == 0}, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}, 
     AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]]]

test3 = MWF[1, 1];
test3[1]
```

> NDSolve`ScaledVectorNorm::urange: The scaling vector has a zero
>   component, so the zero absolute tolerance leads to an unbounded value.
>
> ```
> 4.
> ```

---

Recommended reading:

1. [Plot using With versus Plot using Block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6236808/590388)
2. [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/280)

---

#### Update

I just realized that it is possible to achieve what you want by means of *anonymous* pure function `# &`:

```
MWE1 = b x^2 + a y^2 + 3 + δ;
Dx = D[MWE1, x];
Dy = D[MWE1, y];
MWF[a_, b_] = Function[{δ},
    #1 /. FindRoot[{#2 == 0, #3 == 0}, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]
    ] &[MWE1, Dx, Dy]

test3 = MWF[1, 1];
test3[1]
```

This method utilizes the fact that [*anonymous* pure functions do not rename variables in the nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124583/280).

Comment: Alexey, would you please review my **Related:** links and tell me if you believe this question is a duplicate?

Comment: @Alexey Popkov I tried that method, defining `MWF[aa_, bb_] := 
 Function[{δδ}, 
  Module[{a = aa, b = bb, δ = δδ}, 
   MWE1 /. FindRoot[{Dx == 0, Dy == 0}, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}, 
     AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]]]`  but it does not work. What version of mathematica are you running? I've recently upgraded, may that be source of that difference?

Comment: @Picek `Module` performs *lexical* scoping, so it can't work in place of `Block` where exactly *dynamic* scoping is necessary! Replace `Module` with `Block` and this will work.

Comment: @Picek I have added another solution which doesn't use *dynamic* scoping and despite this doesn't imply any artificial tricks (like fooling enclosing scoping construct in order to avoid renaming of variables).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Taking into account that 3 people already voted for [(10086)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10086/280), I've voted in favor of [(69590)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/280). In my opinion none of the questions you linked to is an exact duplicate of this one but (10086) and (69590) *together* cover the scope of this question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Actually the basic mistake (usage of *lexical* scoping as it would be *dynamic* scoping) is so common and so fundamental that probably it would be even better to create a *dedicated* FAQ question & answer which will explain the essence of the problem and provide links to other answers as examples with more narrow applicability. Then some of those questions could be closed as duplicates of the *dedicated* question. What do you think?

Answer (score 8):

#### Why doesn't it work?

`Evaluate` only has effect at the first level in a held expression.

```
{Hold[1 + 1], Hold[Evaluate[1 + 1]], Hold[f[1 + 1]]}
(* {Hold[1 + 1], Hold[2], Hold[f[1 + 1]]} *)
```

#### Why does `Evaluate` only work at the first level?

Because the evaluator does not look for exceptions beyond the first level inside an expression having a head with [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html).  If it did, it may potentially spend a lot of time scanning large expressions.

Read about evaluation:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressionsOverview.html

#### What's the solution?

Typically one has to use `Replace` or `ReplaceAll`.

```
Function[x, y] /. y -> x^2
(* Function[x, x^2] *)
```

All this falls under the label of [code-generation](/questions/tagged/code-generation), a difficult topic where things may go wrong all too easily due to how Mathematica implements scoping using variable renaming.

Example of how things may go wrong:

Can't we just use `With` instead of `Replace`?  Let's try:

```
With[{y = x^2}, Function[x, y]]

(* Function[x$, x^2] *)
```

Oops!  The function argument got renamed from `x` to `x$` to prevent a name collision.  At the same time it "broke" our function.  This is the reason why `Replace` and `ReplaceAll` are better than `With` for such purposes.

But is `Replace` bulletproof?  Not at all, unfortunately.  When doing such a transformation, we might want to localize `y`.  Let's see what happens.

```
Module[{y},
 Function[x, y] /. y -> x^2
]

(* Function[x$, x^2] *)
```

Oops!  The renaming kicked in again.  (Note: `Block` won't rename here but it's not always a good replacement to `Module`.)

Doing such things can also lead to situations where `SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True]` may make a significant difference (may fix or break things).  This is why Stan Wagon's [FindRoots2D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/713/12) function won't work (as posted on this site) if strict lexical scoping is turned on.

Sometimes we can use [a trick like this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123410/12) to avoid variable renaming:

```
Module[{y}, Function @@ Hold[x, y] /. y -> x^2]
(* Function[x, x^2] *)
```

Writing `Function @@ Hold[...]` instead of `Function[...]` prevents the renaming (for better or worse).

To sum up, code generation seems to be quite difficult in Mathematica.  Caution is advised.  Now if someone could prove me wrong, I would be very happy ... Looking forward to other answers!

Comment: Szabolcs, would you please review my **Related:** links and tell me if you believe this question is a duplicate?

Comment: Would you vote for 13757 as a 2nd duplicate question? I have already voted for 10086.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done, but I suspect you will find it a bit more tricky than you expected. Here is one way to do it. Note that I don't introduce a variable named δ. It is easier to work with [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) ( # ).

```
{a, b, x, y} = Range[4]; (* to ensure scope conflicts assert themselves *)

MWF[a_, b_] =
  Block[{MWE1, Dx, Dy, a, b, x, y},
    MWE1 = b x^2 + a y^2 + 3 + #;
    Dx = D[MWE1, x];
    Dy = D[MWE1, y];
    With[{f = MWE1, dx = Dx, dy = Dy},
      Function[f /.
        FindRoot[{dx == 0, dy == 0}, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}, 
          AccuracyGoal -> ∞]]]]
```

> ```
> 3 + b x^2 + a y^2 + #1 /. 
>   FindRoot[{2 b x == 0, 2 a y == 0}, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}, 
>     AccuracyGoal -> ∞] &
> ```

```
testF = MWF[1, 1]
```

> ```
> 3 + 1 x^2 + 1 y^2 + #1 /. 
>   FindRoot[{2 x == 0, 2 y == 0}, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}, 
>     AccuracyGoal -> ∞] &
> ```

```
Block[{x, y}, testF[1]]
```

[image: msg]

> `4.`

Comment: m_goldberg, would you please review my **Related:** links and tell me if you believe this question is a duplicate?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I would vote for the aggregate of 10086, 13757, and 46751 as constituting a duplicate. Can we close that way? If three people each vote for a different one, would that do it?

Comment: Yes, that would do it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I will vote for 10086 to get things started.

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to use delayed evaluation to work around the issue of variable renaming.

```
MWE1[a_, b_][x_, y_][δ_] := b x^2 + a  y^2 + 3 + δ;
Dx[a_, b_][x_, y_][δ_] := D[MWE1[a, b][x, y][δ], x];
Dy[a_, b_][x_, y_][δ_] := D[MWE1[a, b][x, y][δ], y];
```

Note that one has to introduce a `Module` to properly scope *x* and *y*.

```
MWF[a_, b_] := Module[{x, y}, 
Function[{δ}, (MWE1[a, b][x, y][δ]) /. 
FindRoot[{
  Dx[a, b][x, y][δ] == 0, 
  Dy[a, b][x, y][δ] == 0}, 
  {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]]
]
```

testing confirms that all symbols are properly scoped and that the function can be called

```
a = "test"; b = "test"; x = "test"; y = "test"; δ = "test";;
MWF[1, 1][1]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That works for sure, but it does not have the desired result since the whole point is that in my original calculation `MWE1` is much more complicated and executing derivatives on every allocation of `MWF` must be avoided