# How can I prevent renaming the arguments to Function[{...},...] for making plots of spherical harmonics coloured by phase

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a spherical harmonic coloured by phase.

e.g.

```
psi[l_, m_] := SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ]
sphWithPhase[f_] := 
 SphericalPlot3D[Abs[f]^2, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, Evaluate[Hue[Arg[f]]]], 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
sphWithPhase[psi[1, -1]]
```

But it doesn't work. TracePrint shows that Function[] is renaming its arguments so that then the theta and phi don't match up to the plotted variables.

Whereas e.g.

```
SphericalPlot3D[Abs[psi[1, 1]]^2, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, 
   Evaluate[Hue[Arg[psi[1, 1]]]]]]
```

*does work*.

Can anyone help explain this to me, I find the help pages confusing?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get what you need if you remove the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` and use  `ColorFunction -> 
 Function[{x, y, z, \[Theta]1, \[Phi]1, r}, 
  Hue[Arg[f /. {\[Theta] -> \[Theta]1, \[Phi] -> \[Phi]1}]]]`?

Comment: ... alternatively,  `ColorFunction -> (Hue[Arg[f /. {\[Theta] -> #4, \[Phi] -> #5}]] &)`?

Comment: Related: [(10086)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10086/121)

Comment: I support Lukas Lang's answer and recommendation, but another terse fix: `ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, #] & @ Hue[Arg[f]])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at a simpler example:

```
makeFunc[body_] := Function[{x}, body]
makeFunc[x^2]
(* Function[{x$}, x^2] *)
```

As you've correctly identified, the problem is that the arguments of `Function` are renamed. Interestingly, this replacement is performed during the evaluation of the definition of `makeFunc`, *not* as part of the evaluation of `Function[…]`: The evaluator notices that the expression `body` contains symbols that might clash with the arguments of the `Function[…]` expression. To prevent this from happening, the functions arguments are renamed. Some reading on the topic:

- [Scoping constructs, lexical scoping and variable renamings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia/20776#20776)
- [Variables in Pure Functions and Rules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html)
- [Unexpected variable renaming depending on the form of a pure function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124435/unexpected-variable-renaming-depending-on-form-of-a-pure-function)
- [Local constants](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LocalConstants.html)

To fix the issue, you have a few options:

- Hide the fact that there is a scoping construct:

  ```
  makeFunc[body_] := Function@@Hold[{x}, body]
  makeFunc[x^2]
  (* Function[{x}, x^2] *)
  ```
- Perform a manual replacement of the variables inside the `Function`, as suggested by @kglr:

  ```
  makeFunc[body_]:=Function[{x1}, body /. x -> x1]
  makeFunc[x^2]
  (* Function[{x1$}, x^2 /. x -> x1$] *)
  makeFunc[x^2][y]
  (* y^2 *)
  ```
- Use the "correct" way to pass symbolic expressions ("correct" as in "used by built-in functions and not dependent on magic variable names"): Pass in the symbols as well:

  ```
   makeFunc[body_, sym_] := Function[{sym}, body]
   makeFunc[x^2, x]
   (* Function[{x}, x^2] *)
   makeFunc[y^2, y]
   (* Function[{x}, x^2] *)
  ```

  While it is the most work for the user, this approach has several advantages:

  - It does not break if the user defined `x` as something else already - the user can just choose a different symbol here
  - If you employ the proper `Hold*` attributes, you can even allow the user to reuse already defined symbols, similar to how `Table` localizes its iterator variable.
  - It does not break when used inside a package, since there is no issue with contexts of the symbols
  - It is very clear in intent, since the user doesn't have to know which symbols are to be used, since they have to be manually specified.

Comment: Good lesson, but where is your `sphWithPhase[psi[1, -1]]`?

Comment: Thank you. I have it working now.

Comment: My version: 

    psi[l_, m_] := SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]
    sphWithPhase[f_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
     SphericalPlot3D[Abs[f]^2, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
      ColorFunction -> 
       Function[{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r}, 
       Evaluate[Hue[Arg[f]/(2*\[Pi])]]], PlotRange -> All, 
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
       sphWithPhase[psi[1, -1] + psi[1, 1], \[Theta], \[Phi]]

Answer (score 3):

Here we can use function `Texture[]`. Note that function `Arg[f]` is discontinuous, so there are two sectors without coverage. Create a texture

```
 texture[l_, m_] := 
 DensityPlot[
  Arg[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]], {\[Theta], 0, 
   Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotPoints -> 200, 
  Frame -> False]
```

Now use this to cover

```
sphWithPhase[l_, m_] := 
 SphericalPlot3D[
  Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]]^2, {\[Theta], 0, 
   Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2.01 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Texture[texture[l, m]], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 150]
sphWithPhase[1, -1]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Now we show how to modify the source code to get a similar result. We use a hint from  Mr.Wizard.

```
psi[l_, m_] := SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]
sphWithPhase[f_] := 
 SphericalPlot3D[Abs[f]^2, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r}, #] &@
     Hue[Arg[f]/2/Pi]), PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False]
sphWithPhase[psi[1, -1]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Now we use the hint from  @kglr.

```
psi[l_, m_] := SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]
sphWithPhase[f_] := 
 SphericalPlot3D[Abs[f]^2, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[(Arg[f /. {\[Theta] -> #4, \[Phi] -> #5}] + 
          Pi)/2/Pi] &), PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False]
sphWithPhase[psi[1, -1]]
```

[image: Figure 3]